# Grouping COUNT by Time in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple query that give me the count of application types; it looks something like this:

```
SELECT Application_Type, COUNT(*) FROM Loan_Applications GROUP BY Application_Type;
```

It returns something like this:

```
Home 3
Car  21
Commercial 16
```

There is a field in the database called  ***Submission_Date*** (Of type Date)

How can I query and break up this data by week?

```
Type This week   Last week  2 weeks ago
Home    1            1          1
Car     9            6          6 
Commercial 10        0          3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT
    Application_Type,
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1, 0)) AS 'This week',
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL 1 WEEK AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK, 1, 0)) AS 'Last week',
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE- INTERVAL 2 WEEK AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 WEEK, 1, 0)) AS '2 weeks ago',
FROM Loan_Applications
GROUP BY Application_Type
;
```

Or:

```
SET @date1w  = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 WEEK;
SET @date2w  = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 WEEK;
SET @date3w  = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 WEEK;
SELECT
    Application_Type,
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND @date1w, 1, 0)) AS 'This week',
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN @date1w AND @date2w, 1, 0)) AS 'Last week',
    SUM(IF(Submission_Date BETWEEN @date2w AND @date3w, 1, 0)) AS '2 weeks ago',
FROM Loan_Applications
GROUP BY Application_Type
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a SUMIF type of calculation.  The following sums the number of rows where the submission date is within the last week.

```
SUM(CASE WHEN submission_date >= CURDATE() - 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

You could then repeat this for different ranges, to get any "bands" that you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT 
Application_Type,
SUM(WEEKOFYEAR(Submission_Date) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())) AS `This week`,
SUM(WEEKOFYEAR(Submission_Date) = WEEKOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 WEEK))) AS `Last week`,
SUM(WEEKOFYEAR(Submission_Date) = WEEKOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -2 WEEK))) AS `2 weeks ago`
FROM Loan_Applications GROUP BY Application_Type;
;
```

it is based on the fact that SUM of a boolean expression in the group by will count the cases when the expression is true